# how to insert record in mysql with unique column value using slick api in play framework

Tags: playframework, slick-3.0, play-slick, playframework-2.5

I am new to scala-play framework. I am using Play framework 2.5 and play-slick 1.1.1. I am confused in Future return type when using Action to handle request. I am getting this error:

> found : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result] required: play.api.mvc.Result

in my `registerUser` method.

This is my `registerUser` method

```
def registerUser = Action.async { implicit request =>

registerForm.bindFromRequest.fold(

  errorForm => {
    Future.successful(Ok(views.html.registration(errorForm)))
  },

  user => {
    userDal.isExists(user.email).map { isExists =>

      if(isExists.booleanValue() == false){
        Redirect(routes.UserController.login()).flashing("message"->"Invalid Credential")
      }
      **else{
          userDal.registerUser(user.firstname, user.lastname, user.email, user.password, user.address).map { _ =>

          Redirect(routes.ProductController.index()).withSession("username" -> user.firstname)
        }**
      }
    }
  }
 )
}
```

Here is my table projection and method to insert data into user table. In table 'user', column 'email' is marked as a unique.

Table:

```
private class UserDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {

def id = column[Option[Int]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

def firstname = column[String]("firstname")

def lastname = column[String]("lastname")

def email = column[String]("email")

def password = column[String]("password")

def addr = column[String]("address")

override def * = (id, firstname, lastname, email, password, addr) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)
}
```

method to insert in user table

```
def registerUser(fname: String, lname: String, email: String, password: String, addr: String): Future[User] = db.run {

(userTable.map(u => (u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.password, u.addr))

  returning userTable.map(_.id)
  // And we define a transformation for the returned value, which combines our original parameters with the

  into ((column, id) => User(id, column._1, column._2, column._3, column._4, column._5))) += (fname, lname, email, password, addr)
}
```

I also have method to check whether user with same email is exists or not.
Here is the method

```
def isExists(email: String): Future[Boolean] = db.run{

userTable.filter(_.email === email).exists.result
}
```

If I don't check for existing email through 'isExists' method then it throws SQLException for unique constraints.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's not clear where the error is coming from. Can you note the line where this is thrown?

From the message, it's also a simple type error - you either need to change a method signature, or else map the value of the `Future`.

Comment: Thank you @jkinkead, for replying. In 'registerUser' (first one from the top) method, i have put code in ** code ** which one throws an error mentioned in question.

Comment: Try wrapping the first `Redirect` in `Future.successful`. The two branches of your `if / else` result in different types.

Comment: Then compiler shows same error for first Redirect.

Comment: Try changing the `.map` call to a `.flatMap`.

Comment: Yes, now it solved my problem. This works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jkinkead.

Comment: Posted as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the use of `map` on `userDal.isExists(user.email)`. The `if / else` statement is generating a `Future[Redirect]`, but the `map` call needs an instance of `Redirect`.

In this case, the easiest solution is to replace `map` with `flatMap`, which expects an instance of `Future[Redirect]`.